# bbding symbols with type1 fonts?

Tags: fonts, type1, bbding

I'm using TeXLive 2015 and `bbding` package to show some symbols, but I get type3 fonts for the symbols. How can I get type1 fonts for the output?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\XSolidBold{} \CheckmarkBold{}
\end{document}
```

[image: type3 fonts with bbding]

Comment: Are you keen to build the Type1 version?

Comment: @egreg Isn't it already available? https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/niceframe/fonts/type1/public/niceframe I opened the `bb­d­ing10.pfb` file and it was fine, showing the vector character in `fontforge`. But, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: That PFB file is not in TeX Live, probably because of missing license information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `bbding10.pfb` file and save it in your home tree as `~/texmf/fonts/type1/niceframe/bbding10.pfb` (it's `~/Library/texmf/...` with MacTeX); create the necessary folders. Then add to your document the line

```
\pdfmapline{+bbding10 bbding <bbding10.pfb}
```

Compile.

Full example:

```
\pdfmapline{+bbding10 bbding <bbding10.pfb}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\XSolidBold{} \CheckmarkBold{}
\end{document}
```

The `\pdfmapline` instruction can be anywhere, provided it is before a page is shipped out.

[image]

You may want to make the PFB file available to all users of your machine; in this case you should do, from the directory where you have downloaded `bbding10.pfb`,

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/type1/niceframe
sudo cp bbding10.pfb $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/type1/niceframe
sudo mktexlsr
```

The syntax assumes Bash, modify the command substitution according to your shell.

You'll need the `\pdfmapline` anyway.

In order to remove the need for `\pdfmapline`, prepare a file called `niceframe.map` containing the line

```
bbding10 bbding <bbding10.pfb
```

Then do

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/map/dvips/niceframe
sudo mv niceframe.map $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/map/dvips/niceframe
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap-sys
```

and you'll need no `\pdfmapline` for `bbding10` any more. You can supplement the `niceframe.map` file with other similar entries in case you also download the other Type1 fonts from CTAN in that location. Each time you modify the directory structure in `TEXMFLOCAL`, you need to do `sudo mktexlsr`; if you modify `niceframe.map` you need to do `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: Thanks, worked just fine. :-) I think the pfb font needs more polishing.